# What does $a and -e mean in sed?

Tags: linux, sed, syntax

```
[desktop ~]$ cat sa
sanmesh
shammas
sujil
givin
nepo
bijal

[desktop ~]$ sed -i -e '1i Header' -e '$a Trailor' sa

[desktop ~]$ cat sa
Header
sanmesh
shammas
sujil
givin
nepo
bijal
Trailor
```

Comment: have you tried searching in sed manual? Voting to close

Answer (score 8):

```
sed -i -e '1i Header' -e '$a Trailor' sa
```

`-i`:
Edits the file in place

`-e script`:
Add the script to the commands to be executed

`'1i Header'`:
Match 1st line ('1') and insert ('i') 'Header'

`'$a Trailor'`:
Match last line ('$') and append ('a') 'Trailor'

Comment: Can you please show an example case where `-e` is used effectively?

Comment: `-e` is used effectively in this example

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sed/sed_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: Thank you.  Googling for this answer is 10 times faster than 'searching in sed manual'